# Vue3: adding Google Analytics and GTM script

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, vuejs3

The website is written using Vue3+Vite and Serverside rendering. I'm trying to add Google Analytics script. There are two parts:

1. to simply add a static meta tagline to the header that should be on every page

`<meta name="google-site-verification" content="*" />`

2.To add a script into footer.

Now, I'm okay with the second part. The question is regarding 1: Is there any way to do this simple task without installing vue-meta to the project?

I tried installing vue-meta@next, it's too complicated and not useful for my purpose. All I need is to add a static one line to the top. Overall

Comment: You can always load it with a CDN but it will be more risky, less performant and overall prone to errors. If you don't use all the features of `vue-meta`, it's totally fine to use the package still.